# HMAC + SHA256 jwt secret length

Tags: hash, cryptography, jwt

I will be signing a token with SHA256 and I am wondering on the length of the secret I should put. Does having a secret key length over 256 bits have any benefits if I am using sha256. So if my key is 300 bits long is this more secure?

Comment: This question is not about programming or development, but rather about choosing the right key size. Questions like this are much better suited for [crypto.se] or even [security.se].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The length of the key has to be <= 512 bits because that is the size of the pads. If someone is trying to brute force your key, having a key size of 512 bits will be the most secure.

So to answer your question. Yes, having a key length 300 bits is more secure than one with length 256 bits.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this also apply to SHA512? Does it have then 1024 bits of pads?

Comment: @user2924127 From what I understand, HMAC uses the same pad size for all hash types. Although, you could make your own implementation if you were so inclined.